# Pandas Dataframe add rows on top of dataframe

Tags: pandas, addition, rows

I am trying to add blank rows on top of the pandas Dataframe data. 
Basically, some blank rows and some calculation for each row which contains calculations for Average etc. for that column. Can someone please help me how I can do this?

From:

```
    A   B       D   E   F   G   H   I   J
0   -8  10      532 533 533 532 534 532 532
1   -8  12      520 521 523 523 521 521 521
2   -8  14      520 523 522 523 522 521 522
3   -4  2       526 527 527 528 528 527 529
4   -4  4       516 518 517 519 518 516 518
5   -4  6       528 529 530 531 530 528 530
6   -4  8       518 521 521 521 522 519 521
7   -4  10      524 525 525 525 525 524 524
8   -4  12      522 523 524 525 525 522 523
9   -2  2       525 526 527 527 527 525 527
10  -2  4       518 519 519 521 520 519 520
11  -2  6       520 522 522 522 522 520 523
12  -2  8       551 551 552 552 552 550 552
13  -2  10      533 534 535 536 535 534 535
14  -2  12      537 539 539 539 538 537 539
15  -2  14      528 530 530 531 530 529 530
16  -1  2       518 519 519 521 520 518 520
```

To:

```
A   B       D   E   F   G   H   I   J

            Average 525.6   527.1   527.4   528.0   527.6   526.0   527.4
            Sigma   8.6 8.3 8.5 8.1 8.3 8.3 8.4
            Minimum 516 518 517 519 518 516 518
            Maximum 551 551 552 552 552 550 552




0   -8  10      532 533 533 532 534 532 532
1   -8  12      520 521 523 523 521 521 521
2   -8  14      520 523 522 523 522 521 522
3   -4  2       526 527 527 528 528 527 529
4   -4  4       516 518 517 519 518 516 518
5   -4  6       528 529 530 531 530 528 530
6   -4  8       518 521 521 521 522 519 521
7   -4  10      524 525 525 525 525 524 524
8   -4  12      522 523 524 525 525 522 523
9   -2  2       525 526 527 527 527 525 527
10  -2  4       518 519 519 521 520 519 520
11  -2  6       520 522 522 522 522 520 523
12  -2  8       551 551 552 552 552 550 552
13  -2  10      533 534 535 536 535 534 535
14  -2  12      537 539 539 539 538 537 539
15  -2  14      528 530 530 531 530 529 530
16  -1  2       518 519 519 521 520 518 520
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd be sure that this is actually what you want to do, storing both data and summary statistics in the same frame is a little odd.  That said, you can use `concat` to stack dataframes.

```
In [23]: pd.concat([df.describe(), df])
Out[23]: 
               A        B           D           E           F           G  ...
count  17.000000  17.0000   17.000000   17.000000   17.000000   17.000000   
mean   -3.705882   8.0000  525.647059  527.058824  527.352941  528.000000   
std     2.284861   4.1833    8.866659    8.518147    8.760288    8.396428   
min    -8.000000   2.0000  516.000000  518.000000  517.000000  519.000000   
25%    -4.000000   4.0000  520.000000  521.000000  522.000000  522.000000   
50%    -4.000000   8.0000  524.000000  525.000000  525.000000  525.000000   
75%    -2.000000  12.0000  528.000000  530.000000  530.000000  531.000000   
max    -1.000000  14.0000  551.000000  551.000000  552.000000  552.000000   
0      -8.000000  10.0000  532.000000  533.000000  533.000000  532.000000   
1      -8.000000  12.0000  520.000000  521.000000  523.000000  523.000000   
2      -8.000000  14.0000  520.000000  523.000000  522.000000  523.000000 
...
```

Comment: That looks nice! does df.describe() give the stats?
Also, I think it might be a good idea to have a different sheet for stats, but the reason to have it on the same sheet it to be able to find any data which is an outlier.

Comment: I took your idea and made a few changes and was able to get what I wanted as a start. 
df_blank = pd.DataFrame(index=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], columns=df.columns)
df_concat = pd.concat(df_blank, df)
df_concat = df_concat.reset_index()